# Solving dense linear systems AX = B with CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, cusolver

Can I use the new cuSOLVER library (CUDA 7) to solve linear systems of the form

```
AX = B
```

where `A`, `X` and `B` are `NxN` dense matrices ?

Comment: Yes. In the framework of cuSOLVER you can use QR decomposition, see [QR decomposition to solve linear systems in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399794/qr-decomposition-to-solve-linear-systems-in-cuda). Alternatively, you can calculate the matrix inverse by the successive involation of `cublas<t>getrfBatched()` (which calculates the LU decomposition of a matrix) and `cublas<t>getriBatched()` (which calculates the inverse of the matrix starting from its LU decomposition).

Comment: A final possibility is using `cublas<t>getrfBatched()` followed by a twofold invocation of `cublas<t>trsm()` (which solves upper or lower triangular linear systems).

Comment: the answer will probably vary somewhat based on whether the system is a sparse or a dense system.  @JackOLantern if you want to provide an answer, I would upvote.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks, Robert, for the endorsement. It would be interesting to compare the three above approaches and I hope I will have some time in the next future to do so. The comparison involving the matrix size could be done by constructing random invertible matrices as in [generating a positive invertible matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/136474).

Answer (score 22):

Yes.

**Approach nr. 1**

In the framework of cuSOLVER you can use QR decomposition, see [QR decomposition to solve linear systems in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399794/qr-decomposition-to-solve-linear-systems-in-cuda).

**Approach nr. 2**

Alternatively, you can calculate the matrix inverse by the successive involation of

```
 cublas<t>getrfBatched()
```

which calculates the LU decomposition of a matrix, and

```
cublas<t>getriBatched()
```

which calculates the inverse of the matrix starting from its LU decomposition.

**Approach nr. 3**

A final possibility is using

```
cublas<t>getrfBatched()
```

followed by a twofold invocation of

```
cublas<t>trsm()
```

which solves upper or lower triangular linear systems.

As pointed out by Robert Crovella, the answer may vary on the size and the type of the involved matrices.

**Code for approach nr. 1**

Please, see [QR decomposition to solve linear systems in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399794/qr-decomposition-to-solve-linear-systems-in-cuda).

**Code for approaches nr. 2 and nr. 3**

Below, I'm reporting a worked example for the implementation of approaches nr. `2` and `3`. [Hankel matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) are used to feed the approaches with well-conditioned, invertible matrices. Please, note that approach nr. `3` requires permuting (rearranging) the system coefficients vector according to the pivot array obtained following the invokation of `cublas<t>getrfBatched()`. This permutation can be conveniently done on the CPU.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

#include "cuda_runtime.h" 
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "cublas_v2.h"

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define prec_save 10

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

#define BLOCKSIZEX 16
#define BLOCKSIZEY 16

/************************************/
/* SAVE REAL ARRAY FROM CPU TO FILE */
/************************************/
template <class T>
void saveCPUrealtxt(const T * h_in, const char *filename, const int M) {

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) outfile << std::setprecision(prec_save) << h_in[i] << "\n";
    outfile.close();

}

/************************************/
/* SAVE REAL ARRAY FROM GPU TO FILE */
/************************************/
template <class T>
void saveGPUrealtxt(const T * d_in, const char *filename, const int M) {

    T *h_in = (T *)malloc(M * sizeof(T));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_in, d_in, M * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) outfile << std::setprecision(prec_save) << h_in[i] << "\n";
    outfile.close();

}

/***************************************************/
/* FUNCTION TO SET THE VALUES OF THE HANKEL MATRIX */
/***************************************************/
// --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix
void setHankelMatrix(double * __restrict h_A, const int N) {

    double *h_atemp = (double *)malloc((2 * N - 1) * sizeof(double));

    // --- Initialize random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // --- Generate random numbers
    for (int k = 0; k < 2 * N - 1; k++) h_atemp[k] = rand();

    // --- Fill the Hankel matrix. The Hankel matrix is symmetric, so filling by row or column is equivalent.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            h_A[i * N + j] = h_atemp[(i + 1) + (j + 1) - 2];

    free(h_atemp);

}

/***********************************************/
/* FUNCTION TO COMPUTE THE COEFFICIENTS VECTOR */
/***********************************************/
void computeCoefficientsVector(const double * __restrict h_A, const double * __restrict h_xref, 
                               double * __restrict h_y, const int N) {

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) h_y[k] = 0.f;

    for (int m = 0; m < N; m++)
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
            h_y[m] = h_y[m] + h_A[n * N + m] * h_xref[n];

}

/************************************/
/* COEFFICIENT REARRANGING FUNCTION */
/************************************/
void rearrange(double *vec, int *pivotArray, int N){
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        double temp = vec[i];
        vec[i] = vec[pivotArray[i] - 1];
        vec[pivotArray[i] - 1] = temp;
    }   
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const unsigned int N = 1000;

    const unsigned int Nmatrices = 1;

    // --- CUBLAS initialization
    cublasHandle_t cublas_handle;
    cublasSafeCall(cublasCreate(&cublas_handle));

    TimingGPU timerLU, timerApproach1, timerApproach2;
    double timingLU, timingApproach1, timingApproach2;

    /***********************/
    /* SETTING THE PROBLEM */
    /***********************/
    // --- Matrices to be inverted (only one in this example)
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(N * N * Nmatrices * sizeof(double));

    // --- Setting the Hankel matrix
    setHankelMatrix(h_A, N);

    // --- Defining the solution
    double *h_xref = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) h_xref[k] = 1.f;

    // --- Coefficient vectors (only one in this example)
    double *h_y = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    computeCoefficientsVector(h_A, h_xref, h_y, N);

    // --- Result (only one in this example)
    double *h_x = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    // --- Allocate device space for the input matrices 
    double *d_A; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, N * N * Nmatrices * sizeof(double)));
    double *d_y; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y, N *                 sizeof(double)));
    double *d_x; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_x, N *                 sizeof(double)));

    // --- Move the relevant matrices from host to device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, N * N * Nmatrices * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_y, h_y, N *                 sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /**********************************/
    /* COMPUTING THE LU DECOMPOSITION */
    /**********************************/
    timerLU.StartCounter();

    // --- Creating the array of pointers needed as input/output to the batched getrf
    double **h_inout_pointers = (double **)malloc(Nmatrices * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < Nmatrices; i++) h_inout_pointers[i] = d_A + i * N * N;

    double **d_inout_pointers;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_inout_pointers, Nmatrices * sizeof(double *)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_inout_pointers, h_inout_pointers, Nmatrices * sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    free(h_inout_pointers);

    int *d_pivotArray; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_pivotArray, N * Nmatrices * sizeof(int)));
    int *d_InfoArray;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_InfoArray,      Nmatrices * sizeof(int)));

    int *h_InfoArray  = (int *)malloc(Nmatrices * sizeof(int));

    cublasSafeCall(cublasDgetrfBatched(cublas_handle, N, d_inout_pointers, N, d_pivotArray, d_InfoArray, Nmatrices));
    //cublasSafeCall(cublasDgetrfBatched(cublas_handle, N, d_inout_pointers, N, NULL, d_InfoArray, Nmatrices));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_InfoArray, d_InfoArray, Nmatrices * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < Nmatrices; i++)
        if (h_InfoArray[i] != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Factorization of matrix %d Failed: Matrix may be singular\n", i);
            cudaDeviceReset();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    timingLU = timerLU.GetCounter();
    printf("Timing LU decomposition %f [ms]\n", timingLU);

    /*********************************/
    /* CHECKING THE LU DECOMPOSITION */
    /*********************************/
    saveCPUrealtxt(h_A,          "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\A.txt", N * N);
    saveCPUrealtxt(h_y,          "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\y.txt", N);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_A,          "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\Adecomposed.txt", N * N);
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_pivotArray, "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\pivotArray.txt", N);

    /******************************************************************************/
    /* APPROACH NR.1: COMPUTE THE INVERSE OF A STARTING FROM ITS LU DECOMPOSITION */
    /******************************************************************************/
    timerApproach1.StartCounter();

    // --- Allocate device space for the inverted matrices 
    double *d_Ainv; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_Ainv, N * N * Nmatrices * sizeof(double)));

    // --- Creating the array of pointers needed as output to the batched getri
    double **h_out_pointers = (double **)malloc(Nmatrices * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < Nmatrices; i++) h_out_pointers[i] = (double *)((char*)d_Ainv + i * ((size_t)N * N) * sizeof(double));

    double **d_out_pointers;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_out_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_out_pointers, h_out_pointers, Nmatrices*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    free(h_out_pointers);

    cublasSafeCall(cublasDgetriBatched(cublas_handle, N, (const double **)d_inout_pointers, N, d_pivotArray, d_out_pointers, N, d_InfoArray, Nmatrices));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_InfoArray, d_InfoArray, Nmatrices * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < Nmatrices; i++)
        if (h_InfoArray[i] != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inversion of matrix %d Failed: Matrix may be singular\n", i);
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    double alpha1 = 1.f;
    double beta1 = 0.f;

    cublasSafeCall(cublasDgemv(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, N, &alpha1, d_Ainv, N, d_y, 1, &beta1, d_x, 1));

    timingApproach1 = timingLU + timerApproach1.GetCounter();
    printf("Timing approach 1 %f [ms]\n", timingApproach1);

    /**************************/
    /* CHECKING APPROACH NR.1 */
    /**************************/
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_x, "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\xApproach1.txt", N);

    /*************************************************************/
    /* APPROACH NR.2: INVERT UPPER AND LOWER TRIANGULAR MATRICES */
    /*************************************************************/
    timerApproach2.StartCounter();

    double *d_P; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_P, N * N * sizeof(double)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_y, d_y, N * Nmatrices * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    int *h_pivotArray = (int *)malloc(N * Nmatrices*sizeof(int));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_pivotArray, d_pivotArray, N * Nmatrices * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    rearrange(h_y, h_pivotArray, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_y, h_y, N * Nmatrices * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Now P*A=L*U
    //     Linear system A*x=y => P.'*L*U*x=y => L*U*x=P*y

    // --- 1st phase - solve Ly = b 
    const double alpha = 1.f;

    // --- Function solves the triangular linear system with multiple right hand sides, function overrides b as a result 

    // --- Lower triangular part
    cublasSafeCall(cublasDtrsm(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT, N, 1, &alpha, d_A, N, d_y, N));

    // --- Upper triangular part
    cublasSafeCall(cublasDtrsm(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT, N, 1, &alpha, d_A, N, d_y, N));

    timingApproach2 = timingLU + timerApproach2.GetCounter();
    printf("Timing approach 2 %f [ms]\n", timingApproach2);

    /**************************/
    /* CHECKING APPROACH NR.2 */
    /**************************/
    saveGPUrealtxt(d_y, "D:\\Project\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\solveSquareLinearSystemCUDA\\xApproach2.txt", N);

    return 0;
}
```

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files needed to run such an example are maintained at this [github page](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA-Utilities). The `TimingGPU.cu` and `TimingGPU.cuh` files are maintained at this [github page](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/Timing).

Some useful references on the third approach:

[NAG Fortran Library Routine Document](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/fl/manual/pdf/F07/f07adf.pdf)

[Scientific Computing Software Library (SCSL) User’s Guide](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/manuals/4000/007-4325-001/pdf/007-4325-001.pdf)

https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jjohnson/2010-11/summer/cs680/programs/lapack/Danh/verify_sequential.c

**EDIT**

Timings (in ms) for approaches nr. 2 and 3 (tests performed on a GTX960 card, cc. 5.2).

```
N        LU decomposition       Approach nr. 2       Approach nr. 3
100      1.08                   2.75                 1.28
500      45.4                   161                  45.7
1000     302                    1053                 303
```

As it emerges, approach nr. 3 is more convenient and its cost is essentially the cost of computing the LU factorization. Furthermore:

1. **Solving linear systems by LU decomposition is faster than using QR decomposition** (see [QR decomposition to solve linear systems in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399794/qr-decomposition-to-solve-linear-systems-in-cuda));
2. **LU decomposition is limited to square linear systems, while QR decomposition helps in case of non-square linear systems**.

The below Matlab code can be used for checking the results

```
clear all
close all
clc

warning off

N = 1000;

% --- Setting the problem solution
x = ones(N, 1);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% NxN HANKEL MATRIX %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix
load A.txt
load y.txt

A = reshape(A, N, N);

yMatlab = A * x;
fprintf('Percentage rms between coefficients vectors in Matlab and CUDA %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(yMatlab - y).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(yMatlab).^2))));

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% COMPUTATION OF THE LU DECOMPOSITION %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[Lmatlab, Umatlab] = lu(A);

load Adecomposed.txt
Adecomposed = reshape(Adecomposed, N, N);

L = eye(N);
for k = 1 : N
    L(k + 1 : N, k) = Adecomposed(k + 1 : N, k);
end
U = zeros(N);
for k = 1 : N
    U(k, k : N) = Adecomposed(k, k : N);
end

load pivotArray.txt
Pj = eye(N);
for j = 1 : N
   tempVector = Pj(j, :);
   Pj(j, :) = Pj(pivotArray(j), :);
   Pj(pivotArray(j), :) = tempVector;
end

fprintf('Percentage rms between Pj * A and L * U in CUDA %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(Pj * A - L * U).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(Pj * A).^2))));

xprime      = inv(Lmatlab) * yMatlab;
xMatlab     = inv(Umatlab) * xprime;

fprintf('Percentage rms between reference solution and solution in Matlab %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xMatlab - x).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(x).^2))));

load xApproach1.txt
fprintf('Percentage rms between reference solution and solution in CUDA for approach nr.1 %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xApproach1 - x).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(x).^2))));

load xApproach2.txt
fprintf('Percentage rms between reference solution and solution in CUDA for approach nr.2 %f\n', 100 * sqrt(sum(sum(abs(xApproach2 - x).^2)) / sum(sum(abs(x).^2))));
```