# CUDA - CUBLAS: issues solving many (3x3) dense linear systems

Tags: c++, c, cuda, cublas, cusolver

I am trying to solve about 1200000 linear systems (3x3, Ax=B) with CUDA 10.1, in particular using the CUBLAS library. I took a cue from [this (useful!) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794010/solving-dense-linear-systems-ax-b-with-cuda/28799502#28799502) and re-wrote the suggested code in a Unified Memory version. The algorithm firstly performs a LU factorization using cublasgetrfBatched() followed by two consecutive invocations of cublastrsm() which solves upper or lower triangular linear systems. The code is attached below. It works correctly up to about 10000 matrixes and, in this case, it takes ~570 ms to perform the LU factorization (on an NVIDIA GeForce 930MX) and ~311 ms to solve the systems.

My issues/questions are:

1. Overload issue: it crashes allocating memory for more than 10k matrices. Why? How can I improve my code in order to solve the whole batch of 1.2 million matrices?
2. Time issue: my goal would be to solve all of these systems in less than 1 second. Am I currently following the correct approach? Any suggestions otherwise?
3. Would it be possible and/or useful, and if yes how, to use 'streams' of batches of 10k matrices?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

// CUDA
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cusolverDn.h>

//#include "Utilities.cuh"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

/************************************/
/* COEFFICIENT REARRANGING FUNCTION */
/************************************/
void rearrange(double** vec, int* pivotArray, int N, int numMatrices) {
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      double temp = vec[nm][i];
      vec[nm][i] = vec[nm][pivotArray[N*i + nm] - 1];
      vec[nm][pivotArray[N * i + nm] - 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}


/************************************/
/* MAIN  */
/************************************/
int main() {

  const int N = 3; 
  const int numMatrices = 10000; // I want 1200000

  // random generator to fill matrices and coefficients
  random_device device;
  mt19937 generator(device());
  uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(1., 5.);

  //ALLOCATE MEMORY - using unified memory
  double** h_A;
  cudaMallocManaged(&h_A, sizeof(double*) * numMatrices);
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    cudaMallocManaged(&(h_A[nm]), sizeof(double) * N * N);
  }

  double** h_b;
  cudaMallocManaged(&h_b, sizeof(double*) * numMatrices);
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    cudaMallocManaged(&(h_b[nm]), sizeof(double) * N );
  }
  cout << " memory allocated" << endl;

  // FILL MATRICES
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        h_A[nm][j * N + i] = distribution(generator);
      }
    }
  }
  cout << " Matrix filled " << endl;

  // FILL COEFFICIENTS
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      h_b[nm][i] = distribution(generator);
    }
  }
  cout << " Coeff. vector filled " << endl;
  cout << endl;

  // --- CUDA solver initialization
  cublasHandle_t cublas_handle;
  cublasCreate_v2(&cublas_handle);
  int* PivotArray;
  cudaMallocManaged(&PivotArray, N * numMatrices * sizeof(int));
  int* infoArray;
  cudaMallocManaged(&infoArray, numMatrices * sizeof(int));

  //CUBLAS LU SOLVER
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  cublasDgetrfBatched(cublas_handle, N, h_A, N, PivotArray, infoArray, numMatrices);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
  cout << "It took " << time_span.count() * 1000. << " milliseconds." << endl;


  for (int i = 0; i < numMatrices; i++)
    if (infoArray[i] != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Factorization of matrix %d Failed: Matrix may be singular\n", i);
    }

 // rearrange coefficient 
 // (temporarily on CPU, this step will be on a GPU Kernel as well)
  high_resolution_clock::time_point tA = high_resolution_clock::now();
  rearrange(h_b, PivotArray, N, numMatrices);
  high_resolution_clock::time_point tB = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_spanA = duration_cast<duration<double>>(tB - tA);
  cout << "rearrangement took " << time_spanA.count() * 1000. << " milliseconds." << endl;

//INVERT UPPER AND LOWER TRIANGULAR MATRICES 
  // --- Function solves the triangular linear system with multiple right-hand sides
  // --- Function overrides b as a result 
  const double alpha = 1.f;
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  cublasDtrsmBatched(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT, N, 1, &alpha, h_A, N, h_b, N, numMatrices);
  cublasDtrsmBatched(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT, N, 1, &alpha, h_A, N, h_b, N, numMatrices);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span2 = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t4 - t3);
  cout << "second step took " << time_span2.count() * 1000. << " milliseconds." << endl;
  
  // --- Free resources
  if (h_A) cudaFree(h_A);
  if (h_b) cudaFree(h_b);
 
  cudaDeviceReset();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your memory problem, but please note that for so small matrices, direct methods can be more efficient than LU decomposition. You may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983999/simple-3x3-matrix-inverse-code-c

Comment: may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428924/1695960

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Overload issue: it crashes allocating memory for more than 10k matrices. Why? How can I improve my code in order to solve the whole batch of 1.2 million matrices?

In my opinion, the biggest problem in your code is that you are making horribly inefficient use of managed memory in these key allocation loops:

```
  //ALLOCATE MEMORY - using unified memory
  double** h_A;
  cudaMallocManaged(&h_A, sizeof(double*) * numMatrices);
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    cudaMallocManaged(&(h_A[nm]), sizeof(double) * N * N);
  }

  double** h_b;
  cudaMallocManaged(&h_b, sizeof(double*) * numMatrices);
  for (int nm = 0; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    cudaMallocManaged(&(h_b[nm]), sizeof(double) * N );
  }
```

The problem is that each call to `cudaMallocManaged` has a *minimum granularity*.  That means that if you request to allocate 1 byte, it will actually use up something like 4kbyte of memory (I believe that is the linux allocation granularity.  It looks like you are on windows, and I believe the windows allocation granularity may be larger).  In addition, this creates a huge inefficient data transfer load on the managed memory subsystem, when you launch a kernel (kernels will be launched in your `cublas` calls).

A much better way to do this is to do a single large allocation, rather than the allocation-in-a-loop, and then just subdivide that allocation using pointer arithmetic.  The code could look like this:

```
  //ALLOCATE MEMORY - using unified memory
  double** h_A;
  cudaMallocManaged(&h_A, sizeof(double*) * numMatrices);
  cudaMallocManaged(&(h_A[0]), sizeof(double)*numMatrices*N*N);
  for (int nm = 1; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    h_A[nm] = h_A[nm-1]+ N * N;
  }

  double** h_b;
  cudaMallocManaged(&h_b, sizeof(double*) * numMatrices);
  cudaMallocManaged(&(h_b[0]), sizeof(double) * numMatrices * N);
  for (int nm = 1; nm < numMatrices; nm++) {
    h_b[nm] = h_b[nm-1] + N;
  }
```

Another benefit of this is that the allocation process runs quite a bit faster.

> Time issue: my goal would be to solve all of these systems in less than 1 second. Am I currently following the correct approach? Any suggestions otherwise?

With that change to your code, I am able to run successfully on a 1GB GPU (GeForce GT640), with:

```
const int numMatrices = 1200000;
```

with output like this:

```
$ ./t81
 memory allocated
 Matrix filled
 Coeff. vector filled

It took 70.3032 milliseconds.
rearrangement took 60.02 milliseconds.
second step took 156.067 milliseconds.
```

Your GPU may be somewhat slower, but I think the overall timing should easily come in at less than 1 second.

> Would it be possible and/or useful, and if yes how, to use 'streams' of batches of 10k matrices?

With the above change, I don't think you need to worry about this.  Streams won't help here with overlap of compute operations. They could help with copy/compute overlap (although maybe not much on your GPU) but this would be hard to architect on windows with managed memory. For windows usage, I would probably suggest switching to ordinary CUDA separation of host and device memory, if you want to explore [copy/compute overlap](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/).

As an aside, you may be able to get a set of cublas calls that will do the work even more quickly by using direct inversion.  CUBLAS has a batch direct inversion method.  I normally wouldn't suggest this for solution of linear equations, but it may be something to consider for a set of 3x3 or 4x4 inversions, where you could easily check for singularity with the determinant method.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428924/1695960) is an example.

Comment: Thanks! I tested the code with these corrections and it takes around 600 milliseconds for the whole process (first step + rearrangement + second step), which is pretty good for my purposes. However, I also tested the code with only 3 matrices, in order to check the consistency of the results and it is not giving me the right solution for the systems. I wonder whether I should change/correct any index when filling the matrices?

Comment: I can't tell you what is wrong with code you haven't shown.  As far as I know, this change in allocation scheme shouldn't affect anything about the subsequent usage in the algorithm, or behavior of the algorithm.